# How do I check if a SQL Server datetime column is empty?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

How do I check if a SQL Server datetime column is empty?

Comment: There's no Empty in SQLServer, as all answered, check if it is NULL.

Answer (score 30):

Test it with `IS NULL`.

If using .NET, test against `DBNULL`.

Answer (score 15):

`... WHERE [ColumnName] IS NULL`

Or do you mean something else by "empty" that isn't `NULL`?  Does your column allow `NULL` values?  Are you instead looking for some kind of default value?

Answer (score 6):

To get all rows wtih an empty datetime column you could do this:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE yourdatecolumn IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me in C# , Where

`con` 
is my Sql Connection

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From Transactions WHERE TransactionID = '"+tid+ "'AND InDate IS NULL ", con);
```

Answer (score 0):

net Use IsDBNull or in transact sql use is null.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative to using NULL, you could try:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name = '0000-00-00'
```